# Saving data to excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I am using the following code to write data to 3 different CSV files

```
FileWriter Outputdata_all = new FileWriter("Output_Sheet2.csv");
FileWriter Outputdata = new FileWriter("Output_Sheet3.csv");
FileWriter Index_data= new FileWriter("Output_Sheet1.csv");
```

It works fine ,but how can I change in the code so that the three files come as three sheets in a common output file.

Comment: What you are doing is writing as file not the Microsoft Excel file of csv format. for this, you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: You cannot do that with the csv file format, if you want tabs you have to write in a format native to excel. I'd suggest finding a library that lets you write xlsx file format